# Point to plane distance formula issues

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to derive the formula between a point an a plane using my own method, and i seem to be getting pretty close to the actual formula, but something seems to be really throwing me off, and i can't figure out what.

For a given point $ B $ and plane $ ax + by + cz = d $, the formula is:
$$
d(B,P) = \frac {|aB_x + bB_y + cB_z - d|}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}
$$

My idea is to use the norm vector ( $n$ ), which we are given by the coefficients of the linear equation for the plane. $ n $ is scaled by some scalar $ t $ so that when subtracted from given point $ B $, it's end will give us a point x,y,z that will satisfy the linear equation. Finding the length of this scaled norm will give us the distance between the point and the plane.

$$Equation: ax + by + cz = d $$
$$Point: B$$
$$Norm: n = [a, b, c]$$
$$(B - tn) = (x, y, z)$$
$$(B - tn) \cdot n = d$$
$$B \cdot n - tn \cdot n = d$$
$$B \cdot n - d = tn \cdot n $$
$$\frac {B \cdot n - d} {n \cdot n} = t$$
$$\|tn\| = distance$$
$$|t| \|n\| = distance$$
$$\left|\frac {{B \cdot n - d}} {n \cdot n}\right| \sqrt {n \cdot n} = distance$$
$$\left|\frac {{aB_x + bB_y + cB_z - d}} {a^2 + b^2 + c^2}\right| \sqrt {a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = distance$$

And i can't seem to go any further than that. It seems pretty close, but clearly I'm messing something up, and I can't really seem to figure out what. It feels like this should work.

Any help?

Comment: You’re essentially computing the orthogonal projection of $B$ onto the normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x>0$,
$$ \frac{\sqrt x}{|x|}=\frac{\sqrt x}{x}=\frac1{\sqrt x}$$

Comment: AH! I can safely say that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 >= 0 $, and so i can finish getting the correct formula! So much time spent! Thank you!